# Django CSV Import Slows Down

Tags: python, django, postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

I'm importing a csv list of cities into my Django app. I'm pretty new to Django and Python, and the import runs reasonably quickly, the first 25,000 rows take about 5 minutes, the next 25,000 take 2 hours. I stopped the import and started again where it left off, the next 25,000 took about 4 minutes. Obviously I'm doing it wrong as it appears that it slows down with every insert.

Any help would be great, I'm mainly doing this to learn rather than just importing data, it's currently quicker to just import straight into postgresql so I can keep going with my project, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong so I can get better eith Django / Python.

tia

```
from myapp import Country, State, City

def add_country(isocode, name):
    c = Country.objects.get_or_create(name=name.strip().replace('"', ''), isocode=isocode.strip())[0]
    return c


def add_state(country, isocode, name, statetype):
    country_model = Country.objects.get(isocode=country.strip().lower())
    s = State.objects.get_or_create(name=name.strip().replace('"', ''), isocode=isocode.strip().lower().replace('"', ''), country=country_model, statetype=statetype.strip().replace('"', ''))[0]
    return s


def add_city(country, state, name):
    country_model = Country.objects.get(isocode=country.strip().lower().replace('"', ''))
    try:
        state_model = State.objects.get(name=state.strip().replace('"', ''), country=country_model)
    except State.DoesNotExist:
        state_model = None
    ci = City.objects.get_or_create(name=name.strip().replace('"', ''), state=state_model, postcode='')[0]
    return ci


with open('country.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for counrow in myreader:
        add_country(counrow[0], counrow[1])


with open('state.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for counrow in myreader:
        add_state(counrow[0], counrow[1], counrow[2], counrow[3])


with open('city1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for counrow in myreader:
        add_city(counrow[0], counrow[1], counrow[2])

with open('city2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for counrow in myreader:
        add_city(counrow[0], counrow[1], counrow[2])

with open('city3.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for counrow in myreader:
        add_city(counrow[0], counrow[1], counrow[2])
```

**UPDATE:**

So I've changed the code to use bulk insert, the first group of cities is now just over two minutes, the second lot is 10 minutes, I haven't finished with the third after a couple of hours. There must be some sort of garbage collection process or something that I'm missing, as I've even switched the files around, each file takes the same amount of time when it's run first.

The new code looks like this:

```
def add_country(isocode, name, created_by, changed_by, country_list):
    country_list.append(Country(name=name.strip().replace('"', ''), isocode=isocode.strip()))

def add_state(country, isocode, name, statetype, created_by, changed_by, state_list):
    country_model = Country.objects.get(isocode=country.strip().lower())
    state_list.append(State(name=name.strip().replace('"', ''), isocode=isocode.strip().lower().replace('"', ''), country=country_model, statetype=statetype.strip().replace('"', '')))

def add_city(country, state, name, created_by, changed_by, city_list):
    country_model = Country.objects.get(isocode=country.strip().lower().replace('"', ''))
    try:
        state_model = State.objects.get(name=state.strip().replace('"', ''), country=country_model)
    except State.DoesNotExist:
        state_model = None
    city_list.append(City(name=name.strip().replace('"', ''), state=state_model, postcode=''))

    country_list = []
    state_list = []
    city_list = []

    print "Countries"
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    with open('country.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for counrow in myreader:
            add_country(counrow[0], counrow[1], adminuser, adminuser, country_list)

    Country.objects.bulk_create(country_list)

    print "States"
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    with open('state.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for counrow in myreader:
            add_state(counrow[0], counrow[1], counrow[2], counrow[3], adminuser, adminuser, state_list)

    State.objects.bulk_create(state_list)

    print "Cities 1"
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    with open('city1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for counrow in myreader:
            add_city(counrow[0], counrow[1], counrow[2], adminuser, adminuser, city_list)

    City.objects.bulk_create(city_list)

    print "Cities 2"
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    city_list = []
    with open('city2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for counrow in myreader:
            add_city(counrow[0], counrow[1], counrow[2], adminuser, adminuser, city_list)

    City.objects.bulk_create(city_list)

    print "Cities 3"
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    city_list = []
    with open('city3.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for counrow in myreader:
            add_city(counrow[0], counrow[1], counrow[2], adminuser, adminuser, city_list)

    City.objects.bulk_create(city_list)
```

Comment: Well, `get_or_create` does a search first and then inserts so obviously, it will slow down by every import.

Comment: So after all the changes the final file took 45 mins, so that's 4 minutes for the first, 12 for the second and 45 for the last. I pulled the city imports out and ran them in a separate python file, they take 3 minutes each. There must be something that I am / am not doing here, as the actual imports run quickly, having them run within one file does not. As I said, this is really a learning experience for me, performance is important for all learning, so any tips and info is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the edited code exactly the same code you are running?

Comment: Please, fix the indentation. Look at the line `country=[]` in function `add_city(...)`. That line with the rest of the code shouldn't be part of the function `add_city()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your code for using bulk operation - [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) in the end of the update process.

Comment: This won't help, as he wants `UPSERT`, not just `INSERT`

Comment: OK, bulk_create worked well, i do only need inserts, I noticed my lazy copy and paste of get_or_create when I changed to bulk_create, thanks for the clarification though @khajvah.  <br/>

I'm still seeing a significant slow down still, under two minutes now for the first lot, just under 10 for the second. The third 25K haven't finished yet.  <br/>

is there something wrong with the way I'm doing the read for the csv's?  <br/>

I've also updated the code above to include the three separate csv files for the cities.